# How to use the sqlite zipfile extension with subselect?

Tags: sqlite, zip

I have stored some zip files as blobs in an SQLite database and want to apply the `zipfile` function to get the names of the files stored in the zip files. The table is created in the following way:

```
CREATE TABLE zip_blob( name TEXT, contents BLOB );
```

Zip files are added to the database with the `readfile` function:

```
INSERT INTO zip_blob( name, contents ) VALUES( 'data.zip', readfile('path/to/data.zip') );
```

Later I want to list the contents of the inserted zip blob with the `zipfile` function:

```
SELECT name FROM zipfile(SELECT contents FROM zip_blob WHERE name is 'data.zip');
```

This however result in:

```
Parse error: near "SELECT": syntax error
  SELECT name FROM zipfile(SELECT contents FROM zip_blob WHERE name is 'data.zip
             error here ---^
```

How to pass a blob stored in a table as a column to the `zipfile` function? Note that I cannot use `zipfile( readfile(...) )`, because the zip file no longer exists after it has been stored in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add an addidional set of parenthesis around the inner SELECT, so Sqlite will know it has to take just the first value (since a SELECT normally returns a set of rows)

```
SELECT name FROM zipfile((SELECT contents FROM zip_blob WHERE name is 'data.zip'));
```

Comment: Pretty obvious 